# Adding object to my array of objects using javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a array of objects, I want to add new object into it. so I am using following code here is my code. I have seen other questions asked on the same topic but still I am not able to add my new object that i am fetching using jquery into my list. I am doing silly mistake please find it for me. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>          
    <input placeholder="name" type="text"  id="name"></br>
    <input placeholder="rno" type="text"  id="rollno"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Roll" id="add" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log("loaded");
            var list=[
                      {name:"sud",rno:1},
                      {name:"diya",rno:2},
                      {name:"sakshi",rno:3}
                      ];

            for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){             
                console.log("old list is"+list[i].rno+"\t"+
                    list[i].name);          
            };

            $("#add").click(function(){
                var rno = $("#rollno").val();
                var name = $("#name").val();
               //here i want to add rno and name to my list 
                for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){             
                console.log("new list is"+list[i].rno+"\t"+
                    list[i].name);          
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: list.push({name:"sudarshan",rno:"33"}), you need to use push to add new objects

Comment: Oh thank you sir got it now, list.push({name:name,rno:rno}); but how to add these without using push. I am can we assign using '='

Comment: are u saying list = {name:"sudarshan",rno:"33"}?. this would just end up overwriting your existing array with a new object.you need to use push to add to your existing array

Comment: Yeah got it now I was using new list[list.length] = new {name:name,rno:rno};

Comment: I have seen many people use new while inserting into array of objects what it does??

Comment: the new operator is usually used to create custom objects.you would not be needing this operator for appending to array.this is the best place to start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Sir one more thing I want docs to javascript functions and their usages if you have any link then please provide me thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to append to an array you can use push

```
list.push({name:"sudarshan",rno:"33"});
```

or just

```
list[list.length] = {name:"sudarshan",rno:"33"};
```

which is the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

[Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds items to the end of an array. eg: `arr.push("test");`

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var rno = $("#rollno").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();

    // Use Array#push to add an item to an array.
    // No need to use `new` when using the `{}` syntax for object creation.
    list.push({name:"sudarshan",rno:"33"});

    // Just a tip. You should use `var i = 0;` instead of `i = 0;` to keep the `i` variable out of the global scope.
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){             
        console.log("new list is"+list[i].rno+"\t"+list[i].name);          
    };
});
```